# Google Cloud Storage: how to update cached versions of files?

Tags: php, web, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I have uploaded thousands of files. However, when a user rotates an image in my website I internally update the uploaded version (re-upload the rotated version via PHP to the bucket). But, google keeps displaying the same image again and again.

However, if I append  `?r=[number]`

Where `[number]` is some random number, the updated image is displayed correctly. And if I then remove the `?r=[number]` part from the URL the old image is displayed again.

Is there a way to tell google to update the displayed version?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the cache-control header to private for the uploaded files to ensure that the image is always served fresh, or set the max-age to whatever your maximum bound for staleness is.  See [Cache Control](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#cache-control) in the Google Cloud Storage documentation for details.

Note that after you do this, you'll still need to wait for browser caches containing the original objects expire, but all new images served will use the updated cache control settings.

Comment: What does "served fresh" mean? Will this mean I will have to pay a higher price because of bandwidth?

Comment: Served fresh means that on page load the browser will always perform a GET to Google Cloud Storage to retrieve the image.  If the browser instead serves a cached image (caching the result of a previous GET locally in the browser), the browser never makes a request to Google Cloud Storage to retrieve that image, so the bucket owner is not charged for a GET.